# Prove that a metric space $M$ is compact iff every fully ordered family of closed and non-empty subsets of $M$ has a non-empty intersection.

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

We say that a family of sets $\{A_\lambda\}_{λ\in\Lambda}$ is fully ordered, if given $\lambda,\mu \in \Lambda$, one has $A_\lambda \subset A_\mu$ or $A_\mu \subset A_\lambda$. Prove that a metric space $M$ is compact if, and only if, every fully ordered family of closed and non-empty subsets of $M$ has a non-empty intersection.

Could someone help me?

I tried use Bolzano-Weierstrass property, or more simply, using a theorem relating the compactness and the finite intersection property. But I am not sure how to prove.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Cantor Intersection Theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $M$ is compact and let $(A_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ be a fully ordered family of closed and non-empty subsets of $M$. Suppose that $\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda=\emptyset$. Then $\left(A_\lambda^{\,\complement}\right)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ is an open cover of $M$ and therefore it has a finite subcover $\left(A_\lambda^{\,\complement}\right)_{\lambda\in F}$, where $F$ is a finite subset of $\Lambda$. But there is a $\lambda_0\in F$ such that $(\forall\lambda\in F):A_\lambda\supset A_{\lambda_0}$ and therefore $\bigcap_{\lambda\in F}A_\lambda\supset A_{\lambda_0}$. In particular, $\bigcap_{\lambda\in F}A_\lambda\ne\emptyset$, which is impossible, since$$\left(\bigcap_{\lambda\in F}A_\lambda\right)^\complement=\bigcup_{\lambda\in F}A_\lambda^{\,\complement}=M.$$

And if $M$ is not compact, there is some sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of elements of $M$ without any convergent sequence. Let $A_n=\overline{\{x_n,x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\ldots\}}$. Then each $A_n$ is closed and non-empty, and $(A_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is fully ordered, but $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n=\emptyset$, since any element of $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n$ would be the limit of some subsequence of $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$.